# Question about inline aspx tags

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this div that's got a style attribute..In that I am setting it's background image by calling a function from code behind..

```
<div id="id1" style = "background-image: url(<%=GetImage()%>);"></div>
```

now when I add runat="server" attribute in this div..it shows the Image path as method name itself and not http://localhost/myweb/images/image.jpg

when I remove runat..image path displays alright..Isn't the runat supposed to be there because it's got inline aspx tag ??? I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, runat is not supposed to be there. Since you do not need to access this control on server side, you do not need it.

Comment: but method's gonna run at server side only..this is what is confusing me

Comment: so u mean if I add some attribute to this div in code behind like .. "id1.Attributes.Add(..); " ...only then I need to give runat..right ??

Comment: @Happy Soul yes, you only need `runat="server"` if you need programmatic access to the control from *code-behind*. Remember, the simple fact of it being an `aspx` file means it *will* be processed by the ASP.NET engine, so `<% %>` tags *will* be processed.

Answer (score 3):

Runat controls whether a control instance will be created server side. Dynamic injection directives such as <%=%> are always processed whether runat is set or not.